# Writing mathematical expression with numerator and denominator in markdown github

Tags: github, markdown, mathematical-expressions

I want to write the next expression in readme.md file in my github repository :

[image]

Unfortunately, I could not get the right formula. I have tried the next expression :

```
$$R^2= 1 - {MSE\over Var(y)}= 1- { \sum_{i=1}^{n} ( y_i - \hat{y}_{i} )^2 } \over { \sum_{i=1}^{n}{ (y_i- \overline {y})^2} } }$$
```

I pretty sure that the problem is in the second sum means sum in the denominator

However, I got the next expression:

[image]

Comment: There are some curly bracket issues, so you should instead have `$$R^2= 1 - {MSE\over Var(y)}= 1- {{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} ( y_i - \hat{y}_{i} )^2 } \over { \sum_{i=1}^{n}{ (y_i- \overline {y})^2} } }$$`, but I agree that this does not work in Github Markdown. I agree that having the second sum in the denominator does seem to be the problem.
`

Comment: In fact, it seems, in particular, to be having the subscript _and_ the superscript on the sum in the denominator that causes the issue. If you're happy to remove those, I think it should work.

Comment: So, if your happy with just the subscript i in the sums, try `$$R^2= 1 - \frac{MSE}{Var(y)} = 1- \frac{ \sum_i ( y_i - \hat{y}_{i} )^2 }{\sum_i (y_i- \overline {y})^2} $$` and it should render ok.

Comment: @MattPitkin, exactly the issue is when I am writing the limits. do you think it is better to delete the `{i=1}^{n}` and change it with i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) 3.2.0 (which is the version GitHub currently uses for math rendering) seems to glitch on that particular expression. It seems to be fixed in the latest MathJax version (3.2.2), so one option is to wait for GitHub to upgrade.

Alternatively, it works without the sum indices:

```
$$R^2= 1 - {MSE\over Var(y)}= 1- {{ \sum( y_i - \hat{y}_{i} )^2 } \over { \sum{ (y_i- \overline {y})^2} }}$$
```

[image]